# accessing spark from another class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a class containing a function that processes a spark dataframe.

```
class IsbnEncoder(df: DataFrame) extends Serializable {
  
  def explodeIsbn(): DataFrame = {
    val name = df.first().get(0).toString
    val year = df.first().get(1).toString
    val isbn = df.first().get(2).toString
    
    val isbn_ean = "ISBN-EAN: " + isbn.substring(6, 9)
    val isbn_group = "ISBN-GROUP: " + isbn.substring(10, 12)
    val isbn_publisher = "ISBN-PUBLISHER: " + isbn.substring(12, 16)
    val isbn_title = "ISBN-TITLE: " + isbn.substring(16, 19)
    
    val data = Seq((name, year, isbn_ean),
                (name, year, isbn_group),
                (name, year, isbn_publisher),
                (name, year, isbn_title))
    
    df.union(spark.createDataFrame(data))
    
  } 
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to create a dataframe within the class without creating a new instance of `spark = sparksession.builder().appname("isbnencoder").master("local").getorcreate()`. This is defined in another class in a separate file that includes this file and uses this class(the one I've included). Obviously, my code is getting errors because the compiler doesn't know what spark is.

Comment: can't you just pass an argument of a SparkSession?

Comment: @mck I want it to be easily compatible with new code

Comment: why not return `data` and do the call of `union` in the caller class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trait that extends from serializable and create spark session as a lazy variable and then through out your project in all the objects that you create, you can extend that trait and it will give you sparksession instance.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
trait SparkSessionWrapper extends Serializable {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession.builder().appName("TestApp").getOrCreate()
  }
//object with the main method and it extends SparkSessionWrapper 
object App extends SparkSessionWrapper {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val readdf = ReadFileProcessor.ReadFile("testpath")
   readdf.createOrReplaceTempView("TestTable")
   val viewdf = spark.sql("Select * from TestTable")
 }
}

object ReadFileProcessor extends SparkSessionWrapper{
 def ReadFile(path: String) : DataFrame = {
  val df = spark.read.format("csv").load(path)
  df
 }
}
```

As you are extending the SparkSessionWrapper on both the Objects that you created, spark session would get initialized when first time spark variable is encountered in the code and then you refer it on any object that extends that trait without passing that as a parameter to the method. It works or give you a experience that is similar to notebook.